# Why IsHitTestVisible is not working on Grid and StackPanel in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When I set the the StackPanel or Grid to IsHitTestVisible=false it doesn't work. It keeps react to my mouse or touch.

How can I disable it with affecting the inner objects from interacting?

Thanks,
Sultan